# Question about homicidal tendencies

Tags: discussion, support

Should this new question [new OP](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437783/what-do-you-call-a-person-that-wants-to-kill-people-but-doesnt-actually-kill-th) be forwarded to authorities?

Comment: Why? It's asking for a word, not a method to kill someone.

Comment: a down vote ... seriously!

Comment: Down votes in meta usually express disagreement with your question, not that people think a question is not a good one.

Comment: aye aye ... i've done my civic duty.

Comment: It might have been helpful if someone had asked for a sample sentence (as is generally required for these kinds of requests) before the OP got an accepted answer. Without any further context, it sounds like a pretty standard request, and I don't think there's anything to report. FWIW, I've voted to close as off-topic, sub-reason "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered."

Comment: I guess you are joking....

Comment: Next time... flag the question to the mods who will respond responsibly and appropriately. They'll either say "helpful" or "declined". I think, even if you could correctly identify this person in real life, the police authorities would tell you that the person is not breaking any law. He or she is only asking a question, they have not expressed the desire to murder innocent people. Big difference.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I did flag it too.  Should i have not posted the question on this forum?

Comment: I think you erred on the alarmist side. Let's say the protagonist expressed sadistic pleasure in torturing and killing animals, and it was clear the OP was talking about themself, I would have cast my vote to close, and then cast a vote to delete the question. If the question remained, and earned even a couple of upvotes *then* I would have posted on meta.

Comment: @lbf it's fine to ask in meta. The downvotes to your question most likely indicate that users disagree with the idea that you think it's worth reporting to the authorities.

Comment: If I asked a question about a term that means "eating too much" would you ask to report it to the healthcare authorities?

Comment: @lbf I do not think there is any civic duty involved here but I did pause for thought about this question, myself, and I respect your caution and your highlighting of a possible concern. The user name choice added to my own impression, both the name and the number. Better safe than sorry, and you have done the safe thing. Respect. I have up-voted in order to cancel out just one of the overdone down-votes.

Comment: @NigelJ ... aye!

Answer (score 12):

I don't think so.

It's asking for a word, not displaying any intention to murder or anything.

OP could be a writer, or maybe it's just fun and curiosity behind the question. Either way, it's fine.